# how to install CKeditor 4

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I downloaded CkEditor 4 with plugins from the website and fallow exactly the documentation but I get a blank page

my HTML file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

my html page is blank ; did I miss something ?

my simple page is :
[image: ckeditor]

in console I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of null
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang (ckeditor.js:265)
    at ckeditor.js:873
    at ckeditor.js:873
    at ckeditor.js:1010
ckeditor.js:526 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.loadPart (ckeditor.js:526)
    at n (ckeditor.js:275)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:274)
    at a.n (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13)
    at k (ckeditor.js:272)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:272)
```

Comment: Could you open dev-tools (F12 in Chrome and FF) and see if there is any JavaScript error being reported in Console tab?

Comment: yes there are errors I edited my question to add errors

Comment: You are most likely using a third-party plugin with language files configured incorrectly. I remember I once had such a problem with `selectallcontextmenu` plugin. I would recommend that you first start with plugins only created by CKSource (each plugin has its own website where you can check its author) and when it works start adding custom plugins one by one.

Comment: Third-party plugins are usually ok, but there are some which don't work as intended thus you need to be careful. Fortunately you can easily verify the plugin by looking at its compatibility table (it should support latest version released) and user comments. If there is anything wrong they will let the author know about it. If the author cares about this plugin he will fix this problem. If he does not he will leave it as it is. In such cases I recommend down voting such plugin so that other user could know.

Comment: yes you are correct I used only ckeditor without plugins and its working but with plugins I have the problems

Comment: You could try adding them one by one to see which one is causing this error and simply skip it but leave the rest.

Comment: I did but seems problem is in the plugins, everytime I install one, is not working

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but if one plugin is causing problems for you, could you simply dump it? If a plugin is broken there is no sense using it.

Comment: yes I will try to use tinymce I think is better

Comment: Your choice man however CKEditor is definitely a no.1. Good luck.